# Adding override for onKeyLongPress in Android Phonegap plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am not too familiar with writing plugins for Android, however I would like to implement a long press function for the hardware search button in my Cordova application.

I can successfully do it like this:

```
public class MyClass extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
            Context cntx = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(cntx, "Long Press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

But I am looking for a way to supply the **onKeyLongPress** override in a plugin and not by directly editing MyClass.java as above (the above was just POC).

The way I understand it, is that it should be an override on MyClass, and not CordovaActivity. How can I extend MyClass via my plugin, assuming that my understanding is correct?

I am aware that one can add an event listener like this:

```
document.addEventListener("searchbutton", function (e) {
    //Do stuff here
}, false);
```

However my requirement is a long press.

I have tried the following:

**Creating my plugin and trying to extend my app's class:**

```
public class MyPlugin extends MyClass 
{    
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
            Context cntx = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(cntx, "Long Press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

**Creating my plugin and trying to extend CordovaActivity:**

```
public class MyPlugin extends CordovaActivity 
{    
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
            Context cntx = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(cntx, "Long Press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would post my answer here if anybody ever has the same issue.

I was able to achieve what I needed by doing the following:

```
private void bindKeyEvents(){
    this.webView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    Log.d("testApp", "Release");
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && event.isLongPress()){
                    Log.d("testApp", "Long Press");
                    return true;
                }
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    event.startTracking();
                    Log.d("testApp", "Press");
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }); 
}
```

And called the bindKeyEvents method from my plugin.